# Renaming a wireless access point to match home wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I have a Motorola router and home network called BayVU that my wireless devices connect to, including my Sonos system. I just installed a tp-link EAP225-Outdoor access point which has its own network name.  I want to be able to connect to BayVU on my phone and my Sonos, and when I go outside and lose my connection to BayVU, I don't want to have to manually connect to the TP-Link network as well as change the network that the Sonos system connects to. Can the TP-Link access point be named the same as the indoor network?  Is there a way to solve for this?

Comment: Changing the name is not going to affect the point at which it switches over.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have multiple APs (wireless routers) publishing the same network name (SSID), using the same wireless security type (e.g. WPA2-PSK) and passphrase, then client devices will automatically connect to whichever one they think will suit their needs best (usually whichever one has the highest signal strength). The client devices should also automatically roam to a different AP if the current AP becomes unsuitable, and the other AP is enough better (again, these decisions are usually based on signal strength levels). This is all done on the client and doesn't require the APs be from the same vendor or support any kind of coordination protocol or even know of each others' existence.

Note that some buggy client devices can get a little too "sticky", and stay connected to an AP with poor signal when they should have roamed already. There's not much you can do about that other than splitting the network names again and manually controlling which you switch to. Or maybe upgrading your buggy clients. Some integrated multi-AP systems from a single vendor (including, but not limited to, systems capable of wireless mesh topologies) may have features to allow APs to coordinate with each other and try to "steer" clients to the AP that the network things can best serve the client, but this is tricky because the 802.11 standard leaves all roaming decisions up to the client, so these steering tricks often involve doing nonstandard things to fake out a client into thinking it should roam.